# CSS: scale non-text elements based on the system's font size

Tags: android, html, css, font-size

I'm trying to limit an element to 2 lines of text and I wanted a fallback for `-webkit-line-clamp`. This solution works when the system's default font size is the default:

```
line-height: 1.3em;
max-height: 2.6em;
overflow: hidden;
```

However, on Android, if I change the system's font size, the bottom of the second line is cut off:

[image]

[image]

The font-size is 16px, but with Android's scaling (1.3x), the computed styles are:

```
font-size: 20.8px;
line-height: 27.04px;
max-height: 41.6px;
```

So it looks like `font-size` and `line-height` are scaled, but not `max-height`. Since `max-height` is based on `em`, I expected it to scale too. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I'm not quite understandig as it looks as though in the first CSS you show you have made max-height = 2*line height but in the second set of CSS max-height = 2em. What is your CSS? Could you use a CSS variable for line height and set max-height to twice that (and obviously remove any padding).

Comment: @AHaworth added that the font-size is 16px, but Android is scaling it to 20.8px. The max-height is 2.6*16 as expected

Comment: Why do you expect `max-height` to be scaled when the user modifies their font size preferences? I'm under the impression that it only scales the `font-size` and `line-height` properties because those are the only properties that have anything to do with font size.

Comment: @Spectric right, a possible solution would be making the height of the container scale with the font size somehow. If `max-height` doesn't scale, I don't know if there's other properties or hacks that could scale the height

Comment: @LeoJiang You might have to use JavaScript to get the computed font size and calculate the max height dynamically, or store the font size in a CSS variable and use `calc()` to calculate max height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I had a similar issue. Back then, I solved it by changing the height programmatically.

Doing so, you have the possibility to include the logic needed to implement something like that.

If you do not want to implement this using JavaScript you can do it by using CSS variables and the `calc()` function as it was already mentioned in the comment's section of your question.

Answer (score 0):

> If your text is always two lines, why do you want to set the overflow: hidden and why set the max-height?

I think you should set a `font-size` and `line-height` to text and let div height be auto, if user increase font-size then your div height will be a little larger before was

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't really need `max-height` as a fallback, because `line-clamp` is supported by all modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/css-line-clamp

Wouldn't it be more correct to show the whole text in older browsers instead of reducing the block height? Otherwise users might not realize that the text is cropped.

Anyway, max-height is not necessary if line-clamp is supported:

```css
    @supports (-webkit-line-clamp: 2) {
        .header {
            max-height: none;
        }
    }
```